# Standalone DB with Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm

I have to develop a Spring MVC project. This give user the possibility to work online using normal web access. I also need to give user possibility to work offline.

So I want to develop a standalone java app that the users can install on theirs pc. They can exchange data with server using JSON with Jackson for example.

My question is about the client side. Supposing to handle data with an ORM like Hibernate, which standalone db are best suited for avoid to install DBMS (like mysql, mssql, ...)?

I want to avoid install many software on client.

I have developed a project like this, where the clients are Android tablet, the ORM tool is ormlite and the db sqlite. The db consist in a file.

Thank you for any response!!
Marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd actually recommend [`H2 Database`](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) over `Apache Derby`.  I've used both, and found that `Derby` can be difficult to configure and access in a non-embedded manner (which may not be an issue for you, but it was for me).

`H2` was faster also.

Answer (score 2):

[**Apache Derby**](http://db.apache.org/derby/) works well locally, is embeddable, fast and small (2.5 MB).

If you are more comfortable working with "officially supported" products, you could go with [**JavaDB**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) - it's Derby in disguise.